# Problem with background on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, desktop-background

I have a problem with Ubuntu 13.04, there is no wallpaper except a white one . I tried to change it but it didn't change.

Any suggestions?

Comment: i have the same problem. Just installed ubuntu 13.04 today. Please help. Wallpaper remaisn white, when using Unity or Gnome-Shell too.

Comment: is it possible to re-open the question? Cause now I've git the same bug and 13.04 should be considered stable now.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285568/why-is-my-desktop-background-blank-after-upgrade-to-13-04

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 13.04 is currently still in development so this will likely be resolved once it releases.
And it is policy not to answer to bugs in dev versions.

But to at least give you a hint, could you check if the 'backgrounds' folder is present and has pictures in it?
To do this type

```
nautilus /usr/share/backgrounds
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but there are pictures in this folder . I had the problem when I take picture of my desktop by IprSyst . the screnn became white completly . then I reboot my computer and the wallpaper became white .