# Why is my desktop background black after upgrade to 13.04?

Tags: themes, 13.04, desktop-background, ubuntu-tweak

After I upgraded to 13.04 my desktop background has been a black screen, i.e.:
[image]

**EDITS:** Ubuntu tweak doesn't seem to be able to change the window theme either (although all other themes like icon themes are all easily modifiable). Tweak tool can change the window theme, however.

I have tried the following:

- Changing desktop backgrounds (including back to default)
- Rebooting
- Running the commands in terminal:
  (Which were obtained from the answer to the question, [Unity does not start in Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285627/unity-does-not-start-in-ubuntu-13-04))

`dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ 
 && unity --reset-icons &disown`

and then rebooting (which just changed the colour and size of the unity launcher)

- What is laid out here http://falkvinge.net/2013/02/15/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal/.
- `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ && gnome-session-quit` in terminal
- `unity --reset`
  (which gave the output: `ERROR: the reset option is now deprecated`)
- `unity --replace`
- What's outlined here: https://askubuntu.com/a/286774/93125

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following line pasted into a terminal did  recover the background image for me:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true
```

Hope that helps you too...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to anyone still with this black desktop problem unsolved, to try logging in to another account and checking both Unity and GLX plugins are activated. IE 'opengl' & 'unityshell'.
Use the following command with the `get` option, instead of `reset`, to list them:

```
gsettings reset org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ active-plugins
```

But no guarantees!

Comment: Didn't work I'm afraid