# Unity isn't working after running `unity --replace`

Tags: unity, 13.04

How do I solve this problem? Somebody told me to do it (`unity --replace`) on this question [Why is my desktop background black after upgrade to 13.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285568/why-is-my-desktop-background-blank-after-upgrade-to-13-04) and now it's stuffed.

When I run `unity` I get the following error:

```
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
unity-panel-service: no process found
Killed
```

My output from running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-services` and `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` are:

```
[sudo] password for brentonhorne: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 29.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main unity-services i386 7.0.0daily13.04.18~13.04-0ubuntu1 [29.5 kB]
Fetched 29.5 kB in 1s (20.1 kB/s)       
(Reading database ... 517097 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace unity-services 7.0.0daily13.04.18~13.04-0ubuntu1 (using .../unity-services_7.0.0daily13.04.18~13.04-0ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement unity-services ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up unity-services (7.0.0daily13.04.18~13.04-0ubuntu1) ...
```

and

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-desktop is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

respectively.

Running `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor` gives:

```
[sudo] password for brentonhorne: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for brentonhorne: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dconf-editor
```

EDIT:

```
unity-panel-service: no process found
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
Killed
```

Comment: also look here (http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) for 13.04 procedures. `unity --replace` is deprecated.

Comment: @Takkat I know. I just did that part of the comments to be methodical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Missing unity-services package?

It seems you're missing the `unity-services` package or it is not correctly installed. Just do this on a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-services
```

To ensure that no more packages are missing, try this also:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

### Bad user profile configuration?

Create a new user and test its session. If everything works ok on that user, then the problem is with your user profile. To properly reset all unity-related settings, do this:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
unity --reset-icons
```

Comment: Didn't work. I'll add the output to my question.