# Rebooting Problem

Tags: windows-7, 13.04, live-cd, 32-bit, grubrescue

After experiencing these problems [Why is my desktop background black after upgrade to 13.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285568/why-is-my-desktop-background-blank-after-upgrade-to-13-04), [Unity isn't working after running `unity --replace`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290458/unity-isnt-working-after-running-unity-replace) I realised my best bet would be to uninstall ubuntu and reinstall from scratch. So I logged out of ubuntu (after backing up the files I needed, of course) and into my Windows 7 OS and removed the partition on which Ubuntu had been and downloaded the 13.04 iso file for 32 bit operating systems like the one I had previously burned it to a disk and then I rebooted but when I rebooted I received a grub error, "Error: Unknown File System" and the next line had "grub rescue>". Please help me I have NO idea of where to go from here.

I tried typing, 'F12' to boot from my liveCD instead of my harddrive but this resulted in the same grub rescue screen. I also tried taking the CD out of the drive to see if it would do anything and it didn't.

I know next to zilch when it comes to programming so please just tell me, step-by-step, what I need to do.

I am using a Dell Vostro 3500 laptop with 4x3.7GHz processors and 4GB (I think) RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find your answer here: (scroll down to the 'Restore MBR Part')

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/

Comment: Thank you, so much! You just saved me a lot of time and efort and a day of utter hell and boredom!

Comment: @syflugs ftw you were able to figure this one out when people at Dell weren't and just gave up and decided to replace my HDD.

Comment: Thanx, happy to help!